# How to connect from yahoo kafka manager to secured kafka cluster (SASL_SSL)?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, sasl, yahoo-kafka-manager

I am trying to monitor kafka data using yahoo kafka manager and It's working fine with no security. But with security (`SASL_SSL`), I couldn't see consumers info from consumers tab in yahoo kafka manager.

And I configured consumer.properties file with all the required configurations.

Comment: would you please share your configuration or consumer code that you have?

Comment: Thanks for response.We are using kafka manager, so there is no custom consumer code.

Comment: And following are the consumer properties in KM  security.protocol=SASL_SSL
key.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
value.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
auto.offset.reset=earliest
sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=
ssl.truststore.location=/home/test/jdk1.8.0_77/jre/lib/security/cacerts
ssl.truststore.password=changeit
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="test" password="test-secret";